# Iframe fullscreen problem on android devices

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, iframe, youtube

I have created a cordova hybrid app and in it, I want to display a yt video using iframe, so I have something like this in my code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"
        frameborder="0" 
        allow="encrypted-media; fullscreen" 
        allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
</iframe>
```

This works in diplaying the video in fullscreen on browsers and on iOS but for some reason on android devices it throws this error in the console:

**Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.**

Does anyone have any idea to what could be the cause, and potential solution to this problem?

Comment: [Searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=can+only+be+initiated+by+a+user+gesture&oq=can+only+be+initiated+by+a+user+gesture&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.165j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for this shows many results.  Basically, the browser is blocking it, so there's really not much you can do.

Comment: Yes I thought of something like that. The real puzzle is that it worked a week ago. I should search for some alternatives than.